# How to use search filter in sidenav bar in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use search filter in sidebar so i created search filter and implemented but its now working shown only input field. and i stuck with how to map the items to search filter.

here i attached some of my working code:

```
state = {
  search : ""
}

onchange = e =>{
  this.setState({search : e.target.val })
}

const Menu = ({ resources, onMenuTap, translate }) => {

const {search}=this.state;
  if (search !== "" && resources.name.toLowerCase().indexof(search.toLowerCase()) === -1 ){
    return null
  }

  onchange = e =>{
    this.setState({search : e.target.val })
  }

return (
 <Card className={classes.sidebarCard}>
      {/* Search */}
     <input placeholder="Search" onChange={this.onchange} />
    //
      ....
   //
   );
};
```

Comment: Could you share a simple sample of your code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: you have 2 `onchange` declaration, when you use it. what is the `onMenuTap` fonction ?

Comment: @Nokwiw Yes! added to ```onChnage``` also its not works. and ```onMenuTap``` is nothing, its for someother functionality.

Comment: @MajidM. i have added my code here - https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-worker-i42r4

Comment: Wait, are you using functional component or react Component?

Comment: @Joe `AdminBuilder` is not exist in the code which you attached on `codesandbox`.

Comment: @MajidM. Now i updated. please check

Answer (score 0):

for your onchange, try to use that :

```
onchange = e =>{
  this.setState({search : e.target.value })
}
```

and in your search input :

```
  {/* Search */}
 <input placeholder="Search" value={this.state.search} onChange={(e) => this.onchange(e)} />
```

Comment: i am facing error like "state not define" ```state = { search : "" }``` here.

Comment: are you using functional component or react class Component ?

Comment: I think you use functional component, in this case we can not use this.state, please reffer to https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using functional component. You need to use `useState` hook:

```
  const [search, setState] = useState("");

  if (
    search !== "" &&
    resources.name.toLowerCase().indexof(search.toLowerCase()) === -1
  ) {
    return null;
  }

  onchange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.val);
  };
```

The attached sanbox code is based on your code. But it seems it doesn't render:

[image: Edit icy-hooks-rjpj2]

Answer (score 0):

You are using functional component. So you need to change your code in this way:

```
const Menu = ({ resources, onMenuTap, translate }) => {
const [search, setSearch] = useState(""); //<-- this is your state

 const onchange = e =>{
    setSearch(e.target.val); //set the state
  }

  if (search !== "" && resources.name.toLowerCase().indexof(search.toLowerCase()) === -1 ){
    return null
  }
return (
 <Card className={classes.sidebarCard}>
      {/* Search */}
     <input placeholder="Search" onChange={onchange} value={search} /> //<-- set value equal to search state
    {permissions === "Administrator" && (
        <>
          <MenuItemLink
            className={classes.MenuItemLink}
            activeClassName={classes.active}
            to="/_apps"
            primaryText={translate("easyadmin.apps")}
            leftIcon={
              <AppsOutlined fontSize="small" className={classes.iconColor} />
            }
            onClick={onMenuTap}
          />
          <MenuItemLink
            className={classes.MenuItemLink}
            activeClassName={classes.active}
            to="/_entitys"
            primaryText={translate("easyadmin.customobjects")}
            leftIcon={
              <SettingsOutlinedIcon
                fontSize="small"
                className={classes.iconColor}
              />
            }
            onClick={onMenuTap}
          />
       )}
   );
};
```

Comment: i am facing this error ```"TypeError:Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"```

Comment: @Joe check that `resources.name` prop is not `undefined`